# Importing files from different folders, adding columns with values extracted from each file name?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data-analysis, fread

I'm working with R for some data analysis. I have data saved in separate folders pertaining to the year it originates from. Inside each year folder there's several category folders and each category folder has the .csv and .dat files that need to be imported. The file names are similarly structured in "category_outlet_timeinterval.csv" or ".dat". Each year contains the same categories and each category contains the same type of files, just varying in time interval.

I need to import these files from the several different folders and add a column for Year, Category and Outlet. The values that are to go into these columns need to be read from each file name. After adding the columns, the files will be merged into a single dataframe.

I've got the merging part down using fread:

```
# (1) Create File List
csv_files <- list.files (path       = "R/win-library/Practice", 
                         pattern    = "*.csv",
                         recursive  = T,
                         full.names = T)

# (2) Import All csv with 'fread()'
DATA_ALL <- rbindlist (lapply (csv_files, fread))
view(DATA_ALL)
```

Questions:

-What is the most efficient way I can retrieve the information from the file names as a substring and create the columns accordingly?

-Do I have to make every single file a dataframe or can I do it all from the file list? Main reason for this question is the large size of the files.

I'm a beginner in R and trying to get the hang of it. Sorry if I wasn't clear with anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create columns in your data frame that contain the path and file name information:

```
files <- list.files(path = path,
                    full.names = TRUE,
                    all.files = FALSE,
                    recursive = TRUE)
files <- files[!file.info(files)$isdir]

data <- lapply(files,
               function(x) {
                 data <- read_xls(x, sheet = 1)
                 data$File_name <- basename(x)
                 data$Path <- dirname(x)
                 data
                 })
```

You can then work out from those columns the information (e.g. year) you are after. I would normally use `stringr` functions such as `str_detect` or `str_extract` to extract the relevant information from the file name and path.

Comment: I like this idea! It's simpler than the one I had in mind. Can you briefly explain the code, step by step? I'm kind of lost at what files <- files[!file.info(files)$isdir] does and I'm not very familiar with anonymous functions.


How could I loop through all files in the list and individually add their name and path as columns, then merge them all with rbind?
Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: `list.files` returns both files and directories in the target folder. `file.info()$isdir` returns a boolean vector which tells you which objects are directories. `!` is the  logical negation function. In `files[!file.info(files)$isdir]` we subset the `files` vector and remove those elements that are directories. We are left with a vector containing only the files.
Object `data` is a `list` and as long as the data frames that are the list elements have the same columns you can bind them all together with the `bind_rows` function from `dpyr`. There are many ways to this in R.